# Nginx redirect to 404 page if there is a trailing slash at the end of the URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-config, nginx-location, http-redirect

I got a ask of doing a redirect to 404 page if there is a trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Eg:

```
https://www.example.com/test/
```

If the user enters a trailing slash at the end means we need to redirect it to 404 page. Previously I have redirected the same URL by removing the trailing slash, Now the requirement has changed to redirect to the 404 page.

Here is the nginx conf file for it. Please let me know what change I have to make here to achieve the scenario.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {

  listen 80;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/index =404;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

**Updated Conf:**

Default Nginx 404 error page is displayed after this config. What's the update required here to display the custom 404 page?.

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location ~ ^/(.*)/$ { 
    return 404; 
  }

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/index =404;
    error_page 404 404 /404.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the rewrite `^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` statement and replace it with:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/$ { return 404; }
```

Comment: Hi i did as per u told. but instead of redirecting the custom 404 we created. It redirects to the nginx 404 page. I have attached the screenshot for your reference

Comment: do i have to add the error_page 404 /404.html; to the top

Comment: Yes. The `error_page 404 /404.html;` is not in scope. Best to move it into the `server` block.

Comment: moving it after to the line listen 80. works ?

Comment: You can place it anywhere in the server block context, it makes no difference for the `error_page` directive.

Comment: i have moved the ```error_page 404 /404.html;``` to the top. But site is crashed. I have added the conf for your reference

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to check the configuration.